# Setup NAT Rule for service group

Tags: cisco-asa

We have a Cisco ASA 5515 and I am having trouble setting up the proper NAT rule to route a group of services from a public ip (which is already routing some single ports) to an internal ip.  I am using ASDM to configure but I exported the pertinent parts to command line.

```
    object network IP_147
     host xxx.xxx.xxx.147
    object network Scomage-ESET
     host 10.10.100.11

    object service RDP
     service tcp destination eq 3389 
    object service ESET_2222_2223
     service tcp destination range 2222 2223 
    object service ESET_3128
     service tcp destination eq 3128 
    object service ESET_8443
     service tcp destination eq 8443 
    object-group service ESET
     service-object tcp destination eq https 
     service-object object ESET_2222_2223 
     service-object object ESET_3128 
     service-object object ESET_8443 

    access-list outside_access_in extended permit object RDP any object Scomage-CPC21 
    access-list outside_access_in extended permit object RDP any object Scomage-CPC22 
    access-list outside_access_in extended permit object RDP any object Scomage-CPC23 
    access-list outside_access_in extended permit object-group ESET any object Scomage-ESET 

    object network Scomage-CPC21
     nat (inside,outside) static IP_147 service tcp 3389 9401 
    object network Scomage-CPC22
     nat (inside,outside) static IP_147 service tcp 3389 9402 
    object network Scomage-CPC23
     nat (inside,outside) static IP_147 service tcp 3389 9403
```

IP_147 is the external ip I want to use for this access.  Currently 9401, 9402, and 9403 route to specific internal machines port 3389.  This works just fine.  Unfortunately ASDM won't let me put in a group.  Do I have to do it in command line?  How is this best done?

Comment: Are you saying you want a request to TCP/9401 to translate to TCP/3389 on Scomage-CPC21, TCP/9402 to TCP/3389 on Scomage-CPC22, etc?  I don't understand what you mean about wanting to group them. What would your goal be for grouping them?

Comment: In your example, you cann't group NAT rule

Comment: No.  The three rules to route rdp are working fine.  I wanted to do the same thing with a service group ESET routed to Scomage-ESET.

Comment: I want to send any traffic on ports 2222,2223,3128,8443 coming in on IP_147 to Scomage_ESET.  No port translation is required.

Comment: Thanks Jesse.  The cli solution will be great.  I have been comparing the two against each other and I should be able to figure it out.

Comment: I should clarify, you can group the ports on the access-list but NAT statements can't have object-groups defined - only objects.  However, you can still accomplish what you want (mapping multiple ports to a single host - it's just not quite as clean as you probably hoped for.  Either way, I'm home now and typing the answer out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as I said, you can mostly accomplish what you want (minus an actual object-group to reference in a single NAT statement).

You'll need to create multiple objects all pointed to the same host IP address, but named differently; this will allow you to map multiple ports to the same host without mapping ALL ports and protocols to said host (it will only map the specific ports/protocols).

So, you can add:

```
object network Scomage-ESET-2222
 host 10.10.100.11
 nat (inside,outside) static IP_147 service tcp 2222 2222
!
object network Scomage-ESET-2223
 host 10.10.100.11
 nat (inside,outside) static IP_147 service tcp 2223 2223
!
object network Scomage-ESET-3128
 host 10.10.100.11
 nat (inside,outside) static IP_147 service tcp 3128 3128
!
object network Scomage-ESET-8443
 host 10.10.100.11
 nat (inside,outside) static IP_147 service tcp 8443 8443
!
```

Comment: I wondered if this was the way it had to be done!  Seems strange that a service group is not allowed.  Even the lowly SonicWall firewalls can do that!  Thanks for the clarification. :)

Comment: @JerryWelliver I know.  ASAs are pretty much a standout with this.  Just about every other brand I work with can do it.  I'll have to look again but, I think FXOS can do it too, and that it's just the ASA OS that can't